# Different 404 pages for multisite network in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have created a multisite network in WordPress but I have used same theme for all site and I want to make the 404 page different for all sites. Is this possible with a WordPress multisite network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is the correct syntax (where `$blog_id` is the ID of each site in the multisite installation):

```
<?php
global $blog_id;

if ($blog_id == 2) {
code here;
} 

elseif ($blog_id == 3) {
and here;
} 

else {
and default here;
}
?>
```

You have one 404 file, but you can change the output based on the site ID.